# Extending session object in express-session

Tags: typescript, express, express-session

I know this is not an actual issue, but a help wanted.

I'm struggling with typescript and express session and I have been playing around and trying to fiugure out this one for quite a bit.

I'm trying to extend my session object, for that, I'm trying to do a merge of typings as per in the documentation:

I have a `types/session.d.ts` with the following interface to be merged:

```
declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: string;
  }
}
```

But this is not working, as an example, in `other-folder/some.ts`

```
req.session.userId = user.id;
// Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'.
```

However, if I import `Session` from `express-session`, it does work:

```
import { Session } from 'express-session'

declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: string;
  }
}
```

I'm not very proficient with TypeScript and I'm unsure about importing a module in a type defintion, event TypeScript complains about this (warning):

'Session' is declared but its value is never read.

I'm wondering, is this the right way of tackling the problem?

What can I do different?

Kind regards!

PS: my tsconfig should be fine as I have available through my code other type definitions and they are working with no issues at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). You should also know this from [Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

For example:

`./src/main.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';

const app = express();

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
  }),
);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const user = { id: '1' };
  req.session.userId = user.id;
});
```

`./types/session.d.ts`: Make sure you include at least one top-level `import` or `export` to make this file as a module, NOT a script whose contents are available in the global scope. Sometimes, you will import and use some interfaces or types from third-party node modules. But in your case, you don't need it. So just use `export {}` or `import 'express-session'`, both of them are ok.

```
declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: string;
  }
}

export {};
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./types",
],
```

package versions:

```json
"express": "^4.17.1",
"@types/express": "^4.17.11",
"typescript": "^3.9.7"
"express-session": "^1.17.1",
"@types/express-session": "^1.17.3",
```

Comment: Alright, this seems to work, but I'm kind of skeptical about importing express-session on a d.ts or to export an empty object. I really don't understand it properly. Aren't all files in node consider a module? And why the d.ts file needs to be a module to work? All examples and textbooks I find just do merging without this. I just fear this is a typescript hack.