# Adding additional properties to session object

Tags: typescript, express, express-session

I am trying to add additional properties to session object

```
req.session.confirmationCode = confirmationCode;
```

but getting an error that confirmationCode property does not exist

```
Property 'confirmationCode' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'.
```

I have index.d.ts file under types directory where I am adding this prop

```
declare global {
  namespace session {
    interface SessionData {
      confirmationCode: number;
    }
  }
}

export {};
```

And this is my tsconfig.json file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I saw in source code for @types/express-session package that I can extend session object like

```
declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    confirmationCode: number;
  }
}
```

but when I do this, I get an error that session function is not callable

```
Type 'typeof import("express-session")' has no call signatures
```

How can I extend session object properly?

UPD1: And this is how I call session function

```
app.use(
  session({
    name: "wishlify",
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 60, // 2 months
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: how did you import `express-session` package?

Comment: @slideshowp2 like always `import session from "express-session";` I also added allowSyntheticDefaultImports prop to tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805015/extending-session-object-in-express-session).

I added `export {};` to index.d.ts file and this is now working as expected.

This line makes file not a script but a module.

The final version of index.d.ts file

```
declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    confirmationCode: number;
  }
}

export {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `node_modules > @types > express-session > index.d.ts`, I found the definition for Session like follows. (I removed all the comments)

```
class Session {
  private constructor(request: Express.Request, data: SessionData);
  id: string;
  cookie: Cookie;
  regenerate(callback: (err: any) => void): this;
  destroy(callback: (err: any) => void): this;
  reload(callback: (err: any) => void): this;
    @see Cookie
  resetMaxAge(): this;
  save(callback?: (err: any) => void): this;
  touch(): this;
}
```

I just added the property I wanted in my session, `userId`.

Now my `node_modules > @types > express-session > index.d.ts` looks like:

```
class Session {
  private constructor(request: Express.Request, data: SessionData);
  id: string;
  userId: number; // This is the property I added.
  cookie: Cookie;
  regenerate(callback: (err: any) => void): this;
  destroy(callback: (err: any) => void): this;
  reload(callback: (err: any) => void): this;
    @see Cookie
  resetMaxAge(): this;
  save(callback?: (err: any) => void): this;
  touch(): this;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way to go, but it worked for me.